# Can not move xtz from K1 back to T1 address using Model T Trezor simplestacking wallet

Tags: tezos-client, trezor

I recently purchased a Model T Trezor and 200 XTZ which I thought i could bake using my Trezor.  4 days ago moved tokens to my Tezzigator staking contract and now I receive a warning message when I try to transfer the tokens back to my T1 address.  Can someone advise how I can recover my tokens?[image][image]